# How to disable Zoom from launching at startup

Tags: macos, zoom.app

I'm trying to prevent Zoom to stop launching automatically when I start my Mac.

[image: Users & Groups section of macOS Big Sur System Preferences]
[image]

It's also **not** listed in `~/Library/LaunchAgents` or `/Library/LaunchAgents`.

Could someone suggest a way to prevent it from starting up?

Comment: Doesn‘t Zoom have an option for this in its preferences?

Comment: I wasn't able to find it, but I did see `add Zoom to macOS menu bar`, perhaps that is forcing the app to launch as well, so I've disabled that.

Comment: Are you sure the app was actually launching? Having the menulet in the menu bar is not the same thing.

Comment: Yea, the app popped up in my screen asking me to log in, everytime I started the mac.

Comment: I ABSOLUTELY HATE THIS. Developers think their apps are so important they need to run all the time. No thank you. I'm very selective which apps I allow to run at startup and Zoom is very far from making the cut. Uninstall seems to be the only fix for Zoom.

Comment: For it it just randomly opens sometimes, not even when I have just logged in.

Comment: Is it possible you had it open before you restarted, and you checked 'Reopen current windows'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it by disabling `add Zoom to macOS menu bar` in Zoom's settings.

The question now is why do apps have the right to launch themselves even when I didn't let them via any of the settings. Or why does adding to a menubar launch the app.

[image]

Comment: Zoom doesn't act like this for me.  Is it possible you have a webpage launching in Safari that is calling Zoom?

Comment: This doesn't work for me either. In fact, even after unchecking this, Zoom sill shows up in the menu bar and still starts as soon as I login. Uninstalling Zooms is the only way I've been able to prevent it from running at login.